# actionmailer "from" setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer and in my mailer model, I have a from set like this

```
default :from => "from@example.org"
```

In my environment.rb, I have a different username within

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {}
```

but I'd like the from address to override this.. so that the user sees only that. Is this possible? Additionally, when I change my settings within environment.rb, I don't see my changes take place... do I need to restart my rails server to refresh these settings?

===
here are some of my settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:tls => true,
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => "587",
:domain => '==.org',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name => '===',
:password => '==='
```

}

Comment: yes, you have to restart the server to refresh your settings on environment.rb file.

Comment: Any change you're using Gmail? (Which may be the reason your `default :from...` line is being ignored)

Comment: yes it is! what should i change it to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gmail doesn't let you send as a different user -- it will always make the "From" address the account you're using to sign on (this is for security/spam prevention I believe, that way you can't spoof someone else's address).

Assuming you own the e-mail address(es) you want to send from, there's a way through your Google account to allow sending from those e-mail address(es). Go into the Gmail options, click the "Accounts" section, and click "Add another e-mail address you own."

Comment: This is correct. A small addendum: you could use a service such as SendGrid to send out emails rather than using Google's. Sendgrid allows for 200 a day.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that now it's possible to send emails with a different sender through gmail's SMTP.

I've listed my way to do it here:

[Send an email through gmail but configure a different email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784259/send-an-email-through-gmail-but-configure-a-different-email-address/22787362#22787362)