# ActionMailer Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

this is my first time using ActionMailer. I have a hard time set the sender email.
This is my development.rb :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    user_name:            'foo',
    password:             'mypass',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

And this is my feedback_mailer.rb :

```
class FeedbackMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def feedback_email(feedback, setting_configuration)
    @feedback = feedback
    @setting_configuration = setting_configuration
    mail(to: @setting_configuration.value, :from => feedback.email, subject: @feedback.inquiry_type )
  end
end
```

But the sender email is still foo@gmail.com.
Can I set the sender's email using smtp? Or I have to use sendmail? I tried using :sendmail, instead of smtp, but I have this error :

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -f
```

What should I set in the sendmail? I tried googled it and everything, but nothing worked. Would be really glad, if anyone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks correct.  The "from" argument in the call to mail should set the email address that is on the email.  We're using Sendgrid on Heroku and it works.  This makes me suspect that maybe Google is replacing it with the account holder's email address.  Perhaps test it using another email service and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I couldn't find anything to confirm this on Google's site, but I did find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784936/actionmailer-from-setting.  It seems Google does, in fact, ignore the from field.  If you are using Heroku, Sendgrid is easy to set up and the free version might be all you need. Good luck.

Comment: yes, you are right. Google replacing the from field. thanks, man! I am considering using Sendgrid now