# Action Mailer - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, actionmailer

I am playing around with action mailer, and I don't understand a couple of things

```
class MYMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "bar@gmail.com"
  ....
end
```

in my production.rb file:

```
#config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 111,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'foo@gmail.com',
  password:             'foobar',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto:  true        }
```

1) First of all what is this `default from: "bar@gmail.com"` ?
The from value is read from my production file, and I receive emails from `foo@gmail.com`. So what is the point of `default from: "bar@gmail.com"`

2) Second what is the point of `#config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }` ? I read something on the official guides but I didn't get it. My app still sends email without it..

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784936/actionmailer-from-setting for question #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `Gmail Api` Do not support sent email from different adress(protect from spam/spoof)

2)  `Rails` can send email from self application and this options tell him what host use.