# Send an email through gmail but configure a different email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, actionmailer

I'm trying to send emails from my rails application using GMail's smtp server.

The emails I send appear like sent from my own gmail address, while I would like them to be coming from info@myapp.com.

I've configured the thing using the three ways authentication, and my app has got its unique password. Here's my `production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: 'my ip', 
    protocol: 'https'
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://my ip"
```

and here's my `initializers/smtp.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    enable_starttls_auto: "true",
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "mydomain.com",
    authentication: :plain,
    user_name: 'myusername@gmail.com',
    password: 'mypassword'
  }
end
```

Is it possible? How could I do that?

Comment: so you are receiving email from gmail account but want to look like as your email id..i think use a email forwarder in your info@myapp.com..send to your email then it will send to another email

Comment: You think it's not possible to send an email directly from my app where the sender will look like info@myapp.com?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en it says it's possible from the gmail interface.. I bet it's possible also for sending from my app

Comment: possible duplicate of [actionmailer "from" setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784936/actionmailer-from-setting)

Comment: It is duplicate indeed, thank you for pointing me to that question, in the meantime I managed to find a solution to the problem, should I write it here or close this and answer there? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured my solution,

I have two mailer controllers in my application, one is from devise and sends mail for user registration related stuff, and the other sends emails to me in the from the contacts page.

First let's see the configuration in google. Google allows to send emails with a different sender email, but it requires that you own the mail address, so there's a procedure to follow to verify your email address on google. It's listed [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

I used that procedure to validate my email address: `no_reply@myapp.com` which is the one I want my emails to appear to be `from`

Once gmail has verified that you own the sender email address I configured devise, I changed in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` adding the line:

```
config.mailer_sender = "'myapp_noreply' <no_reply@myapp.com>"
```

Second I went to configure my `app/mailers/notifications_mailer`, by adding the line:

```
default :from => "no_reply@myapp.com"
```

I tested everything and it worked fine. If I check in the email's headers I can still see my gmail account appearing. These look like this:

```
Return-Path: <mygmail@gmail.com>
Received: from myapp.com ([2231:7120::f12c:912f:f12e:5123])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id gn1sm32851027wib.14.2014.04.01.05.20.26
        for <info@casamaroma.it>
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Tue, 01 Apr 2014 05:20:26 -0700 (PDT)
Sender: Giulio <mygmail@gmail.com>
Date: Tue, 01 Apr 2014 12:20:25 +0000
From: 'myapp_noreply' <no_reply@myapp.com>
Reply-To: 'myapp_noreply' <no_reply@myapp.com>
To: destination@email.com
Message-ID: <533aaf09c5237_2b0b123fe8c3341a@server.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Because the `from` field is set to the one I need, I don't care too much for the rest.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this post! This is the gmail alias feature I totally had forgotten about.